# Common elements within 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, c, loops, duplicates, function-definition

I'm trying to write a function that copies all of the values in `source1` which are also found in `source2` into a `destination` and then returns the number of elements copied into the destination.

```c
int common_elements(int length, int source1[length], int source2[length], int destination[length]) 
{
    int counter = 0; 
    int i = 0; 
    while (i < length) {
        int j = 0; 
        while (j < length) {
            if ( source1[i] == source2[j]) {               
                destination[counter] = source1[i];
                counter++; 
            }        
            j++; 
        }
        i++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

The problem is e.g. given `(common_elements(5, {1,2,3,4,5}, {1,2,3,2,1}, []))`, the correct input should be

> ```
> 1,2,3 
> return value: 3
> ```

However, the program is accounting for the duplicates and produces :

> ```
> 1,1,2,2,3 
> return value: 5
> ```

which is incorrect.

How can I remedy this?

Comment: It will be easier if you sort the input arrays first. But otherwise, just search through the output array before adding a number.

Comment: What are you doing to *try* and address duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

In this while loop

```
    int j = 0; 
    while (j < length) {
        if ( source1[i] == source2[j]) {               
            destination[counter] = source1[i];
            counter++; 
        }        
        j++; 
    }
```

you are counting all elements in the array `source2` that are equal to the element `source1[i]`.

I can suggest the following solution provided that the source arrays may not be changed within the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t common_elements( int destination[], 
                        const int source1[], 
                        const int source2[],
                        size_t n ) 
{
    size_t counter = 0; 

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        size_t number = 1;
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < i; j++ )
        {
            if ( source1[i] == source1[j] ) ++number;
        }
        
        for ( size_t j = 0; number && j < n; j++ )
        {
            if ( source1[i] == source2[j] ) --number;
        }
        
        if ( number == 0 ) destination[counter++] = source1[i];
    }
    
    return counter;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 5 };
    int source1[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int source2[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 };
    int destination[N];
    
    size_t n = common_elements( destination, source1, source2, N );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", destination[i] );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3
```